# how to specifically disable one software from connecting to internet?

Tags: windows-8, internet, firewall

so there is this presentation software called prezi. Its business model is this: If you have a free account, the presentation you created will be automatically upload to the cloud and be public, but if you pay a monthly bill, you would have the privacy. So I was thinking if I can specifically disconnect it by blacklist it on the windows firewall, but it seems not in the list at all. any suggetsions?

Comment: The windows firewall only hold things that a rule has already been created for it, by the system creators, the software or you. So make a rule.

Comment: This is a cloud based application. It is the nature of the beast that it needs internet access. If you cut it from the internet, it will probably not work any more. Besides, if the firewall does not do it, there are few options. The only thing I can think of is to run it in a virtual machine and cut the virtual machine from the internet - which is easy in the settings. But as I said, then it probably does not work.